# Use selected column in first query with IN clause in second query

Tags: mysql, join, in-clause

Problem has been recreated below:

```
/* query - 1 */
Select id, title from table1;

/* returns */

id | title
-----------
1  | data-1
2  | data-2
3  | data-3
4  | data-4
5  | data-5
```

I want use this column id's data with IN clause in second query along with join.
Something like this:

```
Select id, title from table1
JOIN
Select anotherColumn from table2 where table2.id IN (1,2,3,4,5) on table1.id = table2.id
```

Instead of manually writing `1,2,3,4,5`, how can I use the column data selected from first query in second query?

EDIT:

Actual query :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT R.id, U.ic_id as rider, U.name, DP.department_name, R.location,
        (R.distance - 1) + 10 as cost , R.timestamp, R.status 
    FROM requests AS R, iconnect.users AS U, iconnect.departments AS DP
    WHERE R.pool = '125' AND R.rider = U.ic_id AND U.department = DP.id
) requestDetails
JOIN
(
    SELECT AVG(rider_rating) AS rider_rating,rider
    FROM
    (
        SELECT rider_rating, R.rider
        FROM journeys AS J, requests AS R
        WHERE J.req_id = R.id AND R.rider IN (12,13) LIMIT 999999
    ) AS allRatings
    GROUP BY rider
) ratingsTable
    ON requestDetails.rider = ratingsTable.rider

/* instead of (12,13) I want to use requestDetails.rider selected from the first derived table */
```

Comment: Using just an `INNER JOIN` should be enough `... INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Minus the chance of duplicates, in which case we can just use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id);
```

Actually, a plain inner join between the two tables would also work.  But, you might want to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in case a given record in `table1` could match more than one record in `table2`.  That would leave us with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.title
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: The actual query is super complex, I added it to the question. Check and see if there's something you can help with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @saibbyweb Your actual query is in a mess, poorly formatted, and I can't really read it.  You should have posted a better question whose answer you could directly have used.

Comment: Ya, I know. Just starting out with mySql. Keeping the recreated problem in reference, can we use the column data selected in first query of the join statement with `IN clause` of second query. I mean, does something like this exist? I can write a sub-query within those IN clause braces which will fix my problem but that way I would be re-selecting the data that I already had in first query. I am just querious (curious) whether it can be used with IN clause of second query or not.